# LayoutManager does not scroll to firstCompletelyVisibleItem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view in my custom layout, which I attach a LinearLayoutManager and my custom adapter.

```
    this.recyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.custom_number_picker_list);
    this.layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    this.recyclerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    this.numberAdapter = new NumberAdapter();
    this.recyclerList.setAdapter(numberAdapter);
```

I want the layoutManager to scroll to the firstCompletelyVisibleItem position.
The command to scroll to this position is just **ignored**!

But if I query for the **first** visible (not complete) position via

```
layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

, and then set this position via

```
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(firstVisible);
```

Then it works gracefully. But if I want to scroll the firstCompletelyVisibleItem,
as said, it is ignored.

Why is that? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: A down vote without a comment is worth nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now I know why this happens. I was just to dump to read the docs!
I would normally remove this question, but as far as I saw, there was 
no question exactly like this, so I provide the answer for future readers.

It's in the docs:

> RecyclerView will scroll the minimum amount that is necessary **to make the
>     target position visible.**

This means, if the item is already fully visible (which it is, if you query for the firstCompletelyVisibleItem), then the recycler view will just not scroll and ignore the request.

I think the key to accomplish this, is to use the scrollToPosition with offest method.